# Which pronoun to use in provided sentence

Tags: grammar

i have a simple yet intriguing me question.

Pronouns used in this sentence are correct?

"I love mountains, i wish i could visit **them** in the winter to see how **they** looks like covered with snow."

And this whole sentente is correct? If not i'll be grateful to you for correcting me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Although we do use the past participle as an adjective before the noun (e.g. *freshly painted fence*) we don't do that with a clause with the present participle (*intriguing me question*) or the past participle (*painted this morning by me fence*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pronouns are correct, but there are some other problems with your sentence.

The correct sentence would be

> I love mountains, I wish I could visit them in the winter to see what they look like covered with snow.

Note that the word "I" is always capitalized.

The other changes are subtle grammatical things that are hard for me to explain.

To correct your entire question, we would have

> I have a simple yet intriguing question.
>
> Are the pronouns used in this sentence correct?
>
> "I love mountains, I wish I could visit them in winter to see what they look like covered with snow".
>
> And this whole sentence is correct? If not I'll be grateful to you for correcting me.
>
> Thanks in advance.

Note that the correct word meaning a word that represents another word is "pronoun". "It", "I", "them", and "they" are all pronouns.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. Now i know everything that i wanted! :)

Answer (score 2):

"I love mountains, i wish i could visit them in the winter to see how they looks like covered with snow."

two things:

(1)  Add "and" before "I wish." There are no "persons" involved here. "They" and "them" are demonstrative pronouns that refer to things, not people, in this sentence.

(2) "...to see how they looks like ..." should be either "to see what they look like covered ... " or "to see how they look covered ..."

Comment: Thanks for reply @Alana. So the whole sentence should be "I love mountains and i wish i could visit them in the winter to see how they look covered with snow." Is that correct now?